# How to pull a Rails 3 Twitter feed without a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

So I am ruby/rails novice and have been looking at: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline  This is the link to the twitter docs for using the 1.1 api.  I am clear that I need a twitter app which I have setup, and that I need to set global vars for the key and secret, but then what.

Should I create a controller method in my Pages_controller (the model for static pages)?
How should I code this method to grab my global vars and then create an instance var that includes my tweets?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say no gem but much easier if you just use the gem [Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter), put the config in a module if you want. It will look something like this

```
twitter_client = Twitter::Client.new(
:consumer_key       => ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"],
:consumer_secret    => ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
:oauth_token        => ENV["OAUTH_TOKEN"],
:oauth_token_secret => ENV["OAUTH_SECRET"],
```

)

In your controller you can then retrieve the tweets with something like

```
 twitter_client.user_timeline('twitter_handle').map(&:attrs)
```

Any further help just ask

Comment: Thanks very much.  I saw this documentation in the GEM docs.  It just seems crazy to use a Gem to load the 3 most recent tweets.  Used to be able to get them with some client side JS... But now with the 1.1 API I have to have all the code to grab them.  I know there is a widget but I want custom look and feel which means pull them on my own.

Comment: Used to... key words there... now we have to validate our request with our credentials, the gem just handles the oauth part, you still get the tweets returned in exactly the same way, so you can still customise them as you normally would

Comment: I decided to just do this.  I was hoping to avoid it but oh well.

Comment: accept answer then? Unfortunately it can no longer be avoided as twitter changed the api